# scala case class too many fields

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to define one case class with 1000 fields in scala REPL 2.11.8.  The case class definition is like:

```
case class Step2_Class(
   `Response` : String,
   `D1` : String,
   `D2` : String,
   `D3` : String,
   `D4` : String,
    //......,
   `D999` : String,
   `D1000` : String)
```

And the REPL is waiting for response. After about 1 hour, following stack overflow exception is thrown out.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.traverseComponents$1(Trees.scala:1294)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itraverse(Trees.scala:1330)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itraverse(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itraverse(SymbolTable.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Traverser.traverse(Trees.scala:2475)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Positions$DefaultPosAssigner.traverse(Positions.scala:288)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Positions$DefaultPosAssigner.traverse(Positions.scala:282)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.traverseComponents$1(Trees.scala:1283)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itraverse(Trees.scala:1330)
```

Do you have any ideas? Does scala not support such case? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Why do you need a class with 1000 fields?

Comment: If the fields are named `D1` to `D1000` why not use an array instead?

Comment: Have you considered doing this instead: `case class Step2_Class(response: String, theDs: List[String])`?

Comment: Such class seems meaningless

Comment: Oo use a vector, array, list, map, what ever don't put 1000 string in a class!

Comment: The input is one CSV file which is the input of one PMML model (Random Forest). In our system, we are trying to parse the CSV file into one case class, and pass through to downstream components (PMML engine) to handle it.

Comment: You have too many fields alright. But the error is probably caused by an infinite loop, not the amount of fields.

Comment: @Guy I don't know anything about java but in compile language you can stack overflow because you allocate a very big variable on the stack.

Comment: @Stargateur If the problem was in creating new `Step2_Class` object it wouldn't fail after an hour.

Comment: A good hint in the question is this line in the stack trace: scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itraverse(Trees.scala:1330). This is called twice, which tells us that your doing something recursive. This in itself is not strange, but even if you do not do infinite recursion, if you're traversing a big data set recursively, without taking care to make your functions tail recursive, you might get this problem. How big is the csv you're using as input? Does your code work properly if you use a smaller csv?

Comment: if  you define in a scala file, does it compile? just to understand if it's a REPL specific problem

Comment: @pedrorijo91 both fails

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the error is not related to the number of fields.

You said that it breaks after some time. Are you sure that you haven't a recursive function without a return condition? The [StackOverFlow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) infact is a runtime error.

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because **an application recurses too deeply**.

If the problem is related to the number of fields it appears at compile time.

While the problem is not related to the number of fields it is a very bad idea to create a code with 1000 parameters, or a class with 1000 fields. As you can imagine there is no real difference between D1 and D15 and D1000, so why don't use an array called D?

Comment: What you are missing is that the compiler _itself_ can throw a runtime exception, including `StackOverflowError`, and judging from `scala.reflect.internal.Trees` in the stack trace that's what happens (a macro call could also lead to that).

Answer (score 1):

Until recently there was a limit of 22 fields in a case class. So it isn't surprising if the compiler (or REPL itself) fails to gracefully handle 1000 fields. You can try to give it more memory (and stack memory in particular) by setting `JAVA_OPTS` (`-Xss` for stack overflow in particular), e.g.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xss8M" scala
```

but you'd have to guess how much, it wouldn't help much with speed (unless it's mostly stuck garbage collecting, which is quite possible), and it could fail with more fields.